# Comparing dates in jquery

Tags: jquery, date-comparison

I am having the following codes and it though i'm having `01-Jan-2009` for `DateTo` and `03-Jan-2009` for `DateFrom` it's reading the values as `NAN`.  Am I missing anything? I`m referencing

```
 var DateToValue = $("#DateTo").val();
      var DateFromValue = $("#DateFrom").val();

      if (Date.parse(DateToValue) <= Date.parse(DateFromValue)) {
          $("#DateFrom").val(DateToValue)
      }
```

> ```
>   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")"
>  type="text/javascript"></script>
>
>  <script  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.datePicker.js")"
> type="text/javascript"></script>
>
>          <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"
>  type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use DateJS for parsing your date. http://www.datejs.com/
just include the script in your html.

Answer (score 19):

How about this?

```
  DateTime DateToValue = $("#DateTo").val();
  DateTime DateFromValue = $("#DateFrom").val();

  if (Date.parse(DateToValue) <= Date.parse(DateFromValue)) {
      $("#DateFrom").val(DateToValue)
  }
```

Answer (score 16):

The Easy Way to Do is

```
 var start= new Date($('#txtstart').val());
 var end= new Date($('#txtend').val());
            if (start < end) {

            }
```

Answer (score 3):

My Comparison with the current date

```
    function isPastDate(dateText) {
// date is dd/mm/yyyy
        var inputDate = dateText.split("/");
        var today = new Date();
        inputDate = new Date(inputDate[2], inputDate[1] - 1, inputDate[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);
        today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return inputDate < today;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer is late, tell me if it is better or not as only this worked for me in v1.10:

```
if($('#DateTo').val().split("/").reverse().join("") <= 
$('#DateFrom').val().split("/").reverse().join("")){//Do something}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to parse through the dates, using the millisecond approach (adding milliseconds present in a day) will not work properly for the daylightsaving.

```
for ( beginDate= new Date(startDate.getTime()); beginDate.getTime()<=endDate.getTime(); beginDate.setDate(beginDate.getDate() + 1)) {
            dateRangeArray.push(new Date(beginDate.getTime()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here's more a simplified way from simple java script

```
<script>
 //get the values
function asdf(){
var fDate=document.forms[0].fromDate.value;
var tDate=document.forms[0].toDate.value;

//Compare

if(fDate>tDate){
        var dateComponentsfrom = fDate.split("/");

//split and convert into date to be more precise

        var fromdate = new Date(dateComponentsfrom[2], dateComponentsfrom[1] - 1, dateComponentsfrom[0]);
        var dateComponentsto = tDate.split("/");
        var todate = new Date(dateComponentsto[2], dateComponentsto[1] - 1, dateComponentsto[0]);
        if(fromdate>todate){
            alert('from date cannot be greater than to date');
            return false;                        
        }
    }
}
</script>
```