# how to check if one date comes before anotherone in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime

I have 2 dates and I one to check if one date comes before another one. 
I know you have to parse the date to a JS date object and then check it with milliseconds.

But the problem is, in my database dateTimes are stored like this.

```
10-mei-2012 09:36
```

So my question is how can I compare two of these dates and check that date 1 comes before date2? Oh and for the record, I am also using jquery to get these values.

```
var dateB = $('#DATUM_BEGIN').val();
var dateE = $('#DATUM_EINDE').val();
```

kind regards

Stef

Comment: I just saw that this question was already asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000693/comparing-dates-in-jquery

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's a function [found while googling](http://dzone.com/snippets/convert-mysql-datetime-js-date) that converts MySQL DATETIME to a JS Object

```
function mysqlTimeStampToDate(timestamp) {
  var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;
  var parts=timestamp.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6").split(' ');
  return new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],parts[3],parts[4],parts[5]);
}
```

Here's one example of how to use it:

```
$(function(){
  var dateB = mysqlTimeStampToDate($('#DATUM_BEGIN').val());
  var dateE = mysqlTimeStampToDate($('#DATUM_EINDE').val());

  if(dateB < dateE){
    // dateB is older
  } else {
    // dateB is newer
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In that format you can compare strings as-is, it is safe. So use just

```
if (dateB < dateE) ...
```

Comment: If that is indeed the format, this is the best. Keep it simple.

Comment: Could downvoter please comment what's wrong with the answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.datejs.com/ could be helpful. it is a jquery Plugin to compare Dates.

Answer (score 0):

The format you show is "mostly" ISO-8601 combined-date format which is by design comparable as plain text.

The only difference between what you have and pure ISO-8601 is that there would need to be a 'T' where the space character is.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

So, if you can sort the strings you know which one comes first.