# compare date jquery mobile

Tags: android, date, jquery-mobile, compare

I would to compare tow date using jquery mobile . but it not working :

```
var date_debut_problem = $("#date_debut_problem").val();
var date_fin_problem = $("#date_fin_problem").val();
if( Date.parse(date_debut_problem) > Date.parse(date_fin_problem) )
{
}
```

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000693/comparing-dates-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. it is working by adding `<script src="js/date.js"></script>`