# Creating a combobox from a list

Tags: python, django, list, combobox

im using django and i have a list of dates

```
list = ["2014-10-26","2010-05-05","1991-12-12" ... ] #This list may grow
```

I want create two comboboxes that have dates like this:

```
combobox1 = 2014-10-26
            2010-05-05
            1991-12-12

combobox2 = 2010-05-05
            1991-12-12
```

and when you select one date in combobox1 in the combobox2 all the dates before the selected disappear, is there a way of doing this? thanks!

edit:

```
list = ["2014-10-26","2010-05-05","1991-12-12","2015-11-26","200-05-05","1999-12-12"]

combobox1
    2014-10-26
    2010-05-05
    1991-12-12
    2015-11-26
    2000-05-05
    1999-12-12

user choose 1991-12-12, in the combobox2 will be like 

combobox2:
2015-11-26
2000-05-05
1999-12-12
```

Comment: Need some more context...what do you mean by dissapear, give an example please...maybe adding what are you going to use it for could help too

Answer (score 0):

To create the select you will want to use a [choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield):

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
('FR', 'Freshman'),
('SO', 'Sophomore'),
('JR', 'Junior'),
('SR', 'Senior'),
)

myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES)
```

Just modify the argument you send as choices. The first value will be the value in your option and the second one will be the displayed text:

```
<option value="FR">Freshman</option>
```

You can use Jquery to do that in the client side using the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "#mySelectId option:selected" ).each(function() {
        if(this_shouldnt_show){
              $(this).hide();
        }
        else{
              $(this).show();
        }
    });
  });
```

You just need to figure out the condition for that to happen but that depends on what you are using in the value field. If you need to compare dates [check this question then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000693/comparing-dates-in-jquery).

Comment: Ok, thanks :) i'll do this later, but my priority right now is take the elements of the list and put them in a normal <select> tag, then i'll figure out how to use it with that jquery code

Comment: Yes! the list i mentioned earlier